# How to test timeout on redux saga

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, redux-saga

I am new in react-native and redux saga.
I would like to cancel may request if the timeout is already 0.

```
Saga

...

const cancelSource = axios.CancelToken.source();

try {
  const { response, timeout } = yield race({
    posts: call(api.callFunction, cancelSource.token),
    timeout: delay(0),
  })

  console.log(response); // return success

  if (timeout) {
    console.log('TIMEOUT', timeout)
    yield cancel();
  }

  ...
} 
catch () {
 if (yield cancelled()) {
   yield call(cancelSource.cancel)
 }
}
finally {
 if (yield cancelled()) {
   yield call(cancelSource.cancel)
 }
}
```

api

```
    callFunction(cancelToken) {
        return axiosClient
            .post(config.baseURL + '/something', {}, {
                cancelToken: cancelToken
            })
            .then((responseJson) => {
                return responseJson;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                return error;
            });
    },
```

but, the result of `timeout` was true since the delay was set to 0. But the `response` is also success.
Therefore the api call was success even though the timeout is already 0.

Am I doing right? or is there another way to cancel the api call if the timeout is already done?.

PS

I also tried the setTimeout then cancel the saga.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "But the response is also success"? Where do you see that?

Comment: Hi @torvin, sorry I forgot to add the log. I updated the source code

Comment: Can't reproduce it. I made an example and it works fine.